# using scope with calculated member

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

I have problem in my calculated member. Whenever this member involve in calculation or query it take large time to execute. I am trying to narrow down execution time. 
I have to remove IIF condition from the members and start using scope instead.

```
CREATE Member CurrentCube.[Measures].[AvgAmount]  as
IIF(ISLeaf([Customer].[ParentCustomer].currentmember),
    [Measures].[Value], 
    (SUM([CCube^Customer].[ParentCustomer].CURRENTMEMBER.CHILDREN) /
     COUNT([Customer].[ParentCustomer].CURRENTMEMBER.CHILDREN))
   ) , 
Format_String = "#.0000000;-#.0000000;0;0",
Non_Empty_Behavior = [Measures].[Amout];
```

I have created hierarchy of customer which is [ParentCustomer] here.  I want to see avg amount of all the children under the parent customer but when I am looking child level which does not have any children in it should only show the [Measures].[Amout].

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Sam

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I assume you really want to have the average of the children, and not the average of all leaf level descendants. The latter could be implemented as follows:

Create a new measure group on the customer dimension table which has a single measure 'customer count' which would just be implemented as count - or of your customer dimension as a granularity that is finer than a single customer - countdistinct of the customer key or something like this.
Then just define your measure as

```
CREATE Member CurrentCube.[Measures].[AvgAmount]  as
    [Measures].[Value] / [Measures].[customer count], 
Format_String = "#.0000000;-#.0000000;0;0",
Non_Empty_Behavior = [Measures].[Amout];
```

This assumes that the aggregation of `[Measures].[Value]` is defined as sum or one of the semi additive aggregations, but not `max` or `min` or something similar.

However, I assume from your question that this is not what you want. Instead you want to see the average of the children at each level. And I assume that `[Customer].[ParentCustomer]` is a standard user hierarchy and not a parent child hierarchy. Then, the approach suggested in the title, using `SCOPE`, would work. Let's assume you have three levels in your `[Customer].[ParentCustomer]` hierarchy:

- The (implicitly defined) All level, just containing the `All` member
- level `A`, built from attribute `A` of the dimension
- level `B`, which is the leaf level and built from attribute `B` of the dimension

Then, under similar assumptions about the `[Measures].[Value]` aggregation, you could define the `AvgAmount` measure as follows:

```
// create the measure as it is correct for level B:
CREATE Member CurrentCube.[Measures].[AvgAmount]  as
    [Measures].[Value], 
Format_String = "#.0000000;-#.0000000;0;0",
Non_Empty_Behavior = [Measures].[Amout];

// overwrite the definition for level A:
SCOPE([Customer].[ParentCustomer].[A].Members);
    [Measures].[AvgAmount] =  [Measures].[Value] / (EXISTING [Customer].[B].[B].Members).Count
END SCOPE;

// overwrite the definition for the ALl level:
SCOPE([Customer].[ParentCustomer].&[All]);
    [Measures].[AvgAmount] =  [Measures].[Value] / (EXISTING [Customer].[A].[A].Members).Count
END SCOPE;
```

This approach, using SCOPE, would not work for a parent child hierarchy, buta syou do not write you have one, I just assume you don`t.